# Simultaneous inference on many gpu, question

Tags: gpu, inference

I want to do boosting for instance segmentation. Lets say I have 5 different models for this and I have 5 GPUs. WHat I want to do is to do the inference on each model on each GPU, and combine the masks on CPU for example. I want to do this in this configuration, because the speed is the limiting factor. If all 5 cards starts to do inference which takes a second lets say, after a second I will have 5 masks generated which normally would take 5 seconds.

Did somebody did try to do it ?
How to approach it.

Comment: What is your question exactly? I'm no expert but I'm sure what you describe is possible:  run the 5 models in parallel, one with each GPU. Please clarify what is the issue.

Comment: please add some details on what you have tried so far and where you are stuck